# Can not connect with loopback address when source is listenning from ipv6

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, cgi, ipv6

I have a server that is listenning a port

```
sockfd = socket(PF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
memset(&addr,0,len = sizeof(addr));
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_port = htons(2000);
addr.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
addr.sin6_scope_id = 0;
addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,len);
listen(sockfd,4);
```

It is waiting at accept

```
.....    
socket = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,&len);
```

I saw "tcp  0  0 :::2000 :::*  LISTEN " with netstat -tan

And i have a client that is trying to connect that server but get error connect() failure, Connection refused

```
memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
addr.sin_port = htons(2000);

if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
     printf("ERROR opening socket\n");

memset(buffer,0x00,sizeof(buffer));
```

I fill the buffer here.

```
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0)
 printf("connect() failure, %s-\n", strerror(errno));
```

I can connect with telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 2000. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to an IP6 server the client should try to establish an IP6 connection.

So you might like to change this:

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(2000);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
```

to be:

```
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_port = htons(2000);
addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_loopback;
```

---

The telnet client propably internally uses `getaddrinfo()` to query whether the host specified via the IP4 address given on telnet's command line has an IP6 service available.

---

Btw: The last parameter to `bind()`  and `connect()` is of type `socklen_t`. The last parameter to `accept()` is of type `socklen_t *`.

Comment: At the server side it accepts bot v4 and v6 connections. I listen four ports at the server and three of them have no problem. I can connect  them with v4 but only have problem with this port. I use cgic and call the cgi from web and it fails. I look wireshark and saw that it sends msg to a different port that i did not mention in the code also it has not listened.

Comment: I filled the buffer at the top before opening the socket and then error changed  to " Network unreachable" I change                        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK); to         addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); then "Connection refused" error came back.

Comment: The server **is** running on the same host as the client? @brknl

Comment: "*... I look wireshark and saw that it sends msg to a different port that i did not mention in the code also it has not listened. ...*" please rephrase, as I'm not sure I got you. @brknl

Comment: I am trying to send it to 2000 but at wireshark log i saw that it is trying to send any other port. It seems that the problem is at htons but i can not find out why exactly. I printed it, printf("\na port = %d.",ntohs(addr.sin_port)); It is correct. It writes 2000.

Comment: I printed htons(2000) also it printed same value with ntohs. Shouldn't they be different?

Comment: Whether host byte order is different from network byte order depends on the endianess of the platform the code is running on. For `x86` it is different, for `PowerPC` it's the same for example. Network byte order is Big-Endian. See here for more on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness @brknl

Comment: You might like to add to your OP how you declare `addr`. @brknl

Comment: It was an endian problem. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. In case you found an anser yourself which is different form the answer given by others, you might like to add an anser to your own question yourself. Just to let upcoming readers see how the issue was solved. If a suitable answer was given by other you are free to upvote those and also accept one. @brknl